# Angular 4 bootstrapped using https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed doesn't load using ngrok

Tags: angular, gulp

I have a very specific weird issue. I have bootstrapped a project using [Boilerplate](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed). The app works fine when I run it locally. For certain dev tasks, I need to use `HTTPS`. I installed `ngrok` and used the following command to expose the app using `HTTPS.

`./ngrok http -host-header=rewrite localhost:5555`
The app runs locally on port `5555`.

The application keeps on loading and doesn't render at all on screen.

I've created an issue for help [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/2456) but as the project is deprecated, I am not expecting any feedback.

Please share your thoughts about how this issue can be tackle.

Have a good day, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use that boilerplate and like you mentioned it is deprecated and was difficult to use. I converted all of my projects to Angular CLI.

I would use the Angular CLI to bootstrap a project. I remember Angular 5 was version 1.7.4 here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli). You will have to find out what version 4 is (if you need version 4) and bootstrap the Angular 4 application using that version of the CLI. The CLI is much more predictable and easier to use and has a bigger and better community where you can get help easier.

I think if you use the CLI to bootstrap the project and then search for your issues with ngrok (if any), you will get better results.

Comment: thank you for your input. Converting the whole app to angular CLI is not an easy option at the moment as the project is in development for quite some time. This is the first time, the team had to use ngrok to implement certain dev tasks.